# What is the shape of this parametric curve?

Tags: geometry

What is the shape of the curve?

\begin{equation} \begin{cases} x=(\cos t)^3\\y=(\sin t)^3\end{cases}\end{equation}

where t is a real parameter.

Comment: It looks like an Astroid

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nstfr62spz

Comment: It is the envelope (or outer limit) of a line segment of unit length one of whose endpoints slides up/down and the other of which slides right/left along the two axes.

Answer (score 2):

It is an  [astroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid)

$x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=1$

The area enclosed is $A=\frac{3}{8}\pi$

perimeter is $L=6$

Hope it is useful
$$...$$

[image: from wikipedia]